# Sorting an Array based on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

`ARRAY.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});`

this code sorts an array from highest to lowest. I have a property that i want it to use to sort the array,
since each element has 3 properties, and one of them is "time" which is what i want it to check and sort based on.

But i can't do `Array.time.sort`. How would i accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value try that?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this works:

`ARRAY.sort(function(b,a){return a.time- b.time});`
"time" being the property you want to access, for me it's time.
To get lowest to highest, replace the locations of `(b, a)`

Comment: That was my solution too

Comment: You figured it outttt